# Use Jimp to convert a .jpg image to png in Node.js (AWS Lamda)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, image-conversion, jimp

I'm writing an AWS Node.js Lambda function (using Serverless) to convert images across different formats (i.e. JPG--> PNG) given an initial URL. I'm using the Jimp library which, according to the documentation, implements this functionality with the code:

```
Jimp.read(JPG_URL, function (err, image) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    image.write("new-image.png")
  }
})
```

now, in my Lambda function I'm using:

```
let img_data = await Jimp.read(JPG_URL);
```

which works well, indeed I can use `img_data` to perform different transformations (i.e. `img_data.greyscale()`). The problem is that (AFAIK) **Lambda's filesystem is read-only** and Jimp doesn't seem to support a way to convert directly to a variable.

How can I perform the conversion without relying on the filesystem?

Comment: You can write up to 512 MB to /tmp directory from lambda. but as lambda runtime instance is reused for multiple invocations while it is hot, make sure to implement a way to make sure you write your data to a unique file path per invocation, and to delete files to avoid reaching tmp directory size limit.

Comment: You can add and efs to lambda.

Comment: @A.Amayreh would the image.write() call write directly to `/tmp` (as default folder) or shall I explicitly write `image.write("/tmp/new-image.png")`?

Comment: @Claus, Checked Jimp documentation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp), it looks you can use the full path as you suggested image.write("/tmp/new-image.png")

Comment: that's great, thanks! Btw you should post this as an answer and I will be happy to accept it so we close the thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try **sharp** like below

```js
const sharp = require("sharp");

async function convert() {
  try {
    await sharp("myfile.jpeg").png({ palette: true }).toBuffer()
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```